# Highlight words in a textview when pressed

Tags: android

I have a TextView to display a paragraph of text and I want my application to speak individual words when they are pressed, using TTS. It would look better if words can be highlighted when pressed. I have implemented it using a ClickableSpan for each word. It works almost fine except that I do not see how to reset the highlighted state back to normal once playback is done. Each time I click a new word the previous word loses the highlight and the new one gets highlighted, but I do not know how to remove the highlight once TTS calls back:

My TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sentence"
    ...
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/i_blue"
 />
```

To fill in the TextView, I use:

```
SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
Iterator<Word> iterator = e.getWordList().iterator();
int wordStart, wordEnd;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Word w =  iterator.next();
    wordStart = strBuilder.length() + w.getPrefix().length();
    wordEnd = wordStart + w.getWord().length();
    strBuilder.append(w.getPrefix() + w.getWord() + w.getSuffix());
    final String currentWord = w.getWord();
    ClickableSpan readWord = new ClickableSpan() {
        private String clickedWord = currentWord;
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Message msg = m_HandlerReadWord.obtainMessage();
            msg.obj = clickedWord;
            m_HandlerReadWord.sendMessage(msg);
        }
        @Override
        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            super.updateDrawState(ds);
            ds.setUnderlineText(false);
        }
    };
    strBuilder.setSpan(readWord, wordStart, wordEnd, 0);
}
m_SentenceView.setText(strBuilder);
m_SentenceView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And I also have this method which is called once TTS calls back when it is done playing the word:

```
public void resetHighlight() {
 //What can I do there to reset any highlighted word?
}
```

Is there a way I can do it? Or is there a better approach than ClickableSpan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a trick that works for me. When the text color in the TextView changes, all highlights are reset. So if I trigger a text color change in the callback of the TTS, then the highlight gets removed. The dirty part is that the triggered color change must be a different color. So I have to change the colors both when TTS calls back and in the onClick handler of the ClickableSpan. And I set these two colors to two almost identical colors.

My ClickableSpan:

```
final int AlmostBlack = m_Resources.getColor(R.color.i_black_almost);
ClickableSpan readWord = new ClickableSpan() {
    private int almostBlack = AlmostBlack;
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView v = (TextView) view;
        v.setTextColor(almostBlack);
        ...
```

And in the handler when TTS calls back:

```
m_SentenceView.setTextColor(m_Resources.getColor(R.color.i_black));
```

If you want to do something similar but without waiting for TTS or anything to call back, you can use a Color State List to trigger color changes when the view is pressed or released:

The Color State List, res/color/clickable_words.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@color/i_black_almost" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/i_black" />
</selector>
```

The TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sentence"
    ...
    android:textColor="@color/clickable_words"
    android:textColorLink="@color/clickable_words"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/i_blue" />
```

Comment: Sylvain can you tell me how can i achieve it ? i need to display each word in toast